# Import error data source of Oracle to Visual Studio (Azure analysys Server)

Tags: visual-studio, oracle11g, azure-analysis-services

When I import data source from oracle and select tables return a error:

```
'On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source. Please install a unified gateway for the server insights.
```

- The build is succeed

What's problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of following reason:

- IP is being used instead of fully qualified Server name while connecting
- If you are using server name, check if it is FQ server name and not missing any keyword

Check and see if it helps.